# Mac Bash Open Chrome to one of the Chrome Settings Tabs

Tags: google-chrome, bash, mac

I'm trying to write a script that opens chrome://net-internals/#dns in a new window so people can clear their internal chrome dns cache. But I can't seem to get it to open. This is on a Mac. How can I do this?

This works:

```
(/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --new-window https://superuser.com)
```

This doesn't:

```
(/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --new-window chrome://net-internals/#dns)
```

Unless someone knows a way to directly clear the Chrome DNS cache directly.

Comment: if you look at [this options list](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/) there is no options for what you look for and as much I know the opening of `chrome://<option>` is not exposed or better said my guess it is blocked as the second parameter will be interpreted as http and others work too, like `ftp://<something>` and when you use chrome it just opens a blank page.

Comment: if you open a blank page (type `about:blank` in the url and the open the developer tools `cmd+option+I`, go to the console window on the bottom and type `window.open("chrome://net-internals")` press enter and you will get the error `Not allowed to load local resources`